# Start Xterm Maximized

Tags: xterm

I want to start xterm in maximized mode. For example: xterm -maximized. Could you suggest me a way (either via command line or via Xdefaults or anything else)?

There is a lot of discussion on Internet and none leads to a solution. I do not want to specify the geometry option, and then specify a large enough geometry. I just want it plain and simple - maximized. Does such an option exist?

Regards,
Ajay.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like xterm supports exactly what you propose (`xterm -maximized`), but only as of Jan. 2009. See the [changelog](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_240).

If you need to make it work with an older version of xterm, I would either try to figure out how to customize your window manager to maximize xterms with a certain resource set, or look for a way to programmatically set the maximize hints described [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#id2551694).

Answer (score 3):

xterm -maximized

generally speaking, PROGRAM -help gives you help in unix.

Comment: Or `program -?`, which is usually a safe way to trigger the `usage()` function and also published in *The New KornShell*, 1995.

Comment: @ClintPachl Most programs don't work with `-?` because the shell interprets `?` as a single-character wildcard.  A lot use `-h` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I added a keyboard shortcut (Super+Intro) with: `xterm -maximized`